# Extracting a mapping from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns `labelId` and `type`. There are many entries with the same `labelId`, but given a `labelId` its `type` is unique. I want to extract this mapping from `labelId` to `type` as a dict. What is the best way to do this?

For the dataframe below:

| Values | labelId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | high |
| 5 | First | high |
| 2 | Second | low |

The expected dict is `{'First': 'high', 'Second': 'low'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it,
drop the duplicates on labelId and type, then choose same columns
and extract as dict

```
dict(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['labelId','Type'])[['labelId','Type']].values)
```

OR
as Abhilash improved on it

```
dict(df[['labelId','Type']].drop_duplicates().values)
```

```
{'First ': 'high', 'Second ': 'low'}
```

Comment: I could improve this to `dict(df[['labelId','Type']].drop_duplicates().values)`.